# как в Discord.py импортировать файл в коги?

Tags: python, discord.py, discord-api

В общем мне нужно сделать так чтобы из одного файла ну скажем 'config.py' в ког импортировалась переменная

у меня при попытке реализовать это просто через `import config` возникает следующая ошибка:

````
  File "C:\Users\Lesha\PycharmProjects\abobius\venv\Lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 941, in _load_from_module_spec
    setup = getattr(lib, 'setup')
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: module 'cogs.exceptions' has no attribute 'setup'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Lesha\PycharmProjects\abobius\TerraWiki-bot\bot.py", line 39, in <module>
    asyncio.run(main())
  File "C:\Users\Lesha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 190, in run
    return runner.run(main)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Lesha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 118, in run
    return self._loop.run_until_complete(task)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Lesha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 653, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Lesha\PycharmProjects\abobius\TerraWiki-bot\bot.py", line 36, in main
    await load()
  File "C:\Users\Lesha\PycharmProjects\abobius\TerraWiki-bot\bot.py", line 32, in load
    await bot.load_extension(f'cogs.{filename[:-3]}')
  File "C:\Users\Lesha\PycharmProjects\abobius\venv\Lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 1013, in load_extension
    await self._load_from_module_spec(spec, name)
  File "C:\Users\Lesha\PycharmProjects\abobius\venv\Lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 944, in _load_from_module_spec
    raise errors.NoEntryPointError(key)
discord.ext.commands.errors.NoEntryPointError: Extension 'cogs.exceptions' has no 'setup' function.```
````

Comment: вы используете `bot.load_extension()` для того, чтобы подключить коги?

Comment: Forevor Base, да

Comment: вы уверены, что добавили `def setup(bot): bot.add_cog(cogname(bot))`

Comment: именно в тот файл в с переменными?

Comment: нет, в сам ког.

Comment: да, конечно добавил